# Trigger inline onchange javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm writing a greasemonkey script that creates an auto-complete search type box which makes it easier to select from a large dropdown on a webpage. The dropdown has inline onchange code which I can't seem to get to trigger when I change the selection using javascript. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the the page had something like:

```
<input onchange="someFunction()">
```

Then your Greasemonkey JavaScript could change the input value and then call the function using:

```
unsafeWindow.someFunction();
```

Comment: Ah. That worked. Any ideas on how you'd stop the enter key from submitting the form?

Comment: @Joren: Open a new question for that and post details.  In general you would change how you bind the event handler and/or use `event.preventDefault();`, `event.stopPropagation();`, and `return false;` in a/the appropriate event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the onchange "really":

From within GM:

```
unsafeWindow.dropdownObject.onchange();
```

From the webpage:

```
dropdownObject.onchange();
```

Answer (score 0):

For tampermonkey, this works simply without using unsafewindow.

Suppose the dropdownbox is defined in webpage something like:

```
<select id="dd_id", onchange="myfunction()">
```

Then following code in userscript triggers the onchange event:

```
document.getElementById('dd_id').onchange();
```

Also, it is suggested to avoid use of unsafewindow in documentation.